# Using Carbon, how to get the translated day name by it's number?

Tags: php, php-carbon

With Carbon, How to get the translated  day name by providing it's number? (in the current locale)

giving that I have day number 1, I want to get Monday in english, Lunes in spanish, Montag in german and so on.

and only by using Carbon, I don't want to use kind of arrays of translated days.

I tried the Carbon::getDays() method which returns the array of day names, but Unfortunately, only in english.

Comment: Use `formatLocalized()` and set the locale to your desired language.

Comment: @volcaniCody I guess there is not a supported by carbon, unless you use a custom function

Comment: @Qirel I tried to use formatLocalized, but I think it should be used on a giving date, what I need is to get the translated day name of a giving number (0-6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If getting the day name is your only concern, you can do this with an array.

```php
$weekdays = Carbon::getDays();
```

However, if you need a way to get the name for a locale there's 2 ways to go about it.

1. Use translation strings (in resources/lang folder. Need to be manually added)
2. Use Carbon:

```php
Carbon::create($weekdays[$day])->locale($locale)->dayName;
// Carbon::create($weekdays[1])->locale('fr_FR')->dayName outputs 'lundi'
// Carbon::create($weekdays[1])->locale('es_ES')->dayName outputs 'lunes'
// Carbon::create($weekdays[1])->locale('en_US')->dayName outputs 'monday'
```

Alternatively, find a year that starts with a monday and you can avoid making a week days array. However, be sure to comment why you chose that specific year.

Comment: this worked Carbon::create($weekdays[$day])->locale($locale)->dayName;

Answer (score 1):

```
Carbon::setLocale('es');
```

try this, for Spanish or de for German and so on,

Comment: even I set Carbon::setLocale('es'), the getDays method always return days in english

Comment: It's not recommended to do this anymore.


Previously there was Carbon::setLocale that set globally the locale. But as for our other static setters, we highly discourage you to use it. It breaks the principle of isolation because the configuration will apply for every class that uses Carbon.


https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization (scroll down a little bit)

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty - but this works:

`Carbon::now()->year(2018)->dayOfYear(1)->locale('de')->dayName`

**EDIT:**

`Carbon::now()->year(2019)->dayOfYear(0)->locale('de')->dayName`

Comment: actually, the param I want to get the day string from is the weekday (0 - 6)

Comment: Change the year to 2019, and the dayOfYear for the day number (0-6)

Answer (score 0):

This version will return the localized day name using the application locale.

`collect(Carbon::getDays())->map(fn($dayName) => ucfirst(Carbon::create($dayName)->dayName));`